# Problemas con consulta del tipo (CASE , JOIN) de sql server en eloquent de laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Mientras realizaba el tipo de consultas CASE ,JOIN de sql server en eloquent de laravel obtuve un error:

en la siguiente consulta hago uso de selectRaw para hacer una consulta con del tipo CASE pero asi mismo realizo lo que seria un JOIN de la siguiente manera (liqui_lab.leyes_imsur) que es un atributo del modelo Liquidaciones_laboratorio y es en este punto por el cual me sale el error q muestro 
haciendo uso de tinker

```
$li=IMSUR\Liquidaciones::with(['liqui_lab','proveedor_p'])->where('cod_prove
edor','6869')->selectRaw("cod_liquidacion, CASE liqui_lab.leyes_imsur WHEN 'SI'
THEN 'cargas lista' ELSE 'no lista' END AS stado")->get();


Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not fou
nd: 1054 Unknown column 'liqui_lab.leyes_imsur' in 'field list' (SQL: select cod
_liquidacion, CASE liqui_lab.leyes_imsur WHEN 'SI' THEN 'cargas lista' ELSE 'no
lista' END AS stado from `liquidaciones` where `cod_proveedor` = 6869)'
```

luego de cambiar (liqui_lab.leyes_imsur) que es del modelo Liquidaciones_laboratorio por (estado) del modelo Liquidaciones si me corre aunq proveedores tb me sale null.

```
>>> $li=IMSUR\Liquidaciones::with(['liqui_lab','proveedor_p'])->where('cod_prove
edor','6869')->selectRaw("cod_liquidacion, CASE estado WHEN 'SI' THEN 'cargas li
sta' ELSE 'no lista' END AS stado")->get();
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#789
     all: [
       IMSUR\Liquidaciones {#770
         cod_liquidacion: "631819",
         stado: "cargas lista",
         liqui_lab: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#802
           all: [
             IMSUR\Liquidaciones_laboratorio {#805
               cod_liquidacion_laboratorio: 243523,
               cod_liquidacion: "631819",
               entregado_laboratorio: "SI",
               fecha_entregado: "2019-08-21 10:08:29",
               usuario_entregado: "CCASTRO",
               leyes_imsur: "SI",
               fecha_leyes_imsur: "2019-08-21 16:35:42",
               usuario_leyes_imsur: "FVI├æOLA",
             },
           ],
         },
         proveedor_p: null,
       },
       IMSUR\Liquidaciones {#771
         cod_liquidacion: "639519",
         stado: "cargas lista",
         liqui_lab: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#769
           all: [
             IMSUR\Liquidaciones_laboratorio {#810
               cod_liquidacion_laboratorio: 243605,
               cod_liquidacion: "639519",
               entregado_laboratorio: "SI",
               fecha_entregado: "2019-08-28 15:38:50",
               usuario_entregado: "GQUISPE",
               leyes_imsur: "SI",
               fecha_leyes_imsur: "2019-08-29 09:25:03",
               usuario_leyes_imsur: "FVI├æOLA",
             },
           ],
         },
         proveedor_p: null,
       },
       IMSUR\Liquidaciones {#783
         cod_liquidacion: "305319",
         stado: "cargas lista",
         liqui_lab: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#752
           all: [],
         },
         proveedor_p: null,
       },
```

lo que indica que la llamada del atributo leyes_imsur del modelo Liquidaciones_laboratorio esta mal ,  como puedo solucionar eso

aqui tambien dejo mis modelos relacionados

modelo Liquidaciones_laboratorio

```
class Liquidaciones_laboratorio extends Model
{
    protected $table='liquidaciones_laboratorio';
    protected $primaryKey='cod_liquidacion_laboratorio';
    protected $fillable=['cod_liquidacion_laboratorio',
                         'cod_liquidacion',
                         'entregado_laboratorio',
                         'fecha_entregado',
                         'usuario_entregado',
                         'leyes_imsur',
                         'fecha_leyes_imsur',
                         'usuario_leyes_imsur'];

    public function lab_l(){
      return $this->belongsTo('IMSUR\Liquidaciones','cod_liquidacion');
    }
}
```

modelo liquidaciones

```
class Liquidaciones extends Model
{
    protected $table='liquidaciones';
    protected $primaryKey = 'cod_liquidacion';
    protected $fillable = ['cod_columna',
                           'cod_liquidacion',
                           'clave_muestra',
                           'fecha_ingreso',
                           'fecha_liquidacion',
                           'cod_proveedor',
                           'particula',
                           'cod_cooperativa',
                           'cod_transportista',
                           'observaciones',
                           'cod_origen',
                           'cheque',
                           'anticipo_',
                           'cheque_',
                           'trans_1',
                           'TMB',
                           'TARA',
                           'HUM',
                           'TMH',
                           'TMS',
                           'IMSUR_ZN',
                           'ZINC',
                           'IMSUR_DM',
                           'PLATA_DM',
                           'IMSUR_PLOMO',
                           'PLOMO',
                           'CLIENTE_ZN',
                           'PRECIO_ZN',
                           'CLIENTE_DM',
                           'PRECIO_AG',
                           'CLIENTE_PLOMO',
                           'PRECIO_PLOMO',
                           'monto',
                           'mas_transporte',
                           'importe_total',
                           'estado',
                           'debe',
                           'cod_grupo_liquidacion',
                           'usuario_ingreso',
                           'usuario_liquidacion',
                           'costo_dolar',
                           'plataforma',
                           'triturado',
                           'pago_transporte',
                           'cod_persona',
                           'devuelto'];

    public function proveedor_p(){
      return $this->belongsTo('IMSUR\Proveedores','cod_proveedor');
    }

    public function liqui_lab(){
      return $this->hasMany('IMSUR\Liquidaciones_laboratorio','cod_liquidacion');
    }
```

modelo Proveedores

```
    class Proveedores extends Model
{
    protected $table='proveedores';
    protected $primaryKey = 'cod_proveedor';
    protected $fillable=['cod_proveedor',
                         'proveedor',
                         'cod_cooperativa',
                         'cod_origen'];

    public function liqui_p(){
      return $this->hasMany('IMSUR\Liquidaciones','cod_proveedor');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Vamos a solucionar lo sencillo primero:

Para que se vea la relación `proveedor_p` en el resultado, debes cargar la llave que «conecta» las dos tablas, entonces, en el select debe estar incluido el campo `cod_proveedor`.

Algo así:

```
IMSUR\Liquidaciones::with(['liqui_lab','proveedor_p'])
    ->where('cod_proveedor','6869')
    ->select('cod_liquidacion', 'cod_proveedor')
    ...
```

---

En cuanto al CASE, veo que es un resultado sencillo lo que haces (mostrar un mensaje u otro), por lo cual yo buscaría más bien jugar con la lógica de las colecciones de Laravel y acomodar los datos a nivel de aplicación, y no de base de datos.

Esto lo sugiero, teniendo en cuenta que no hay una forma sencilla de trabajar con CASE en tablas relacionadas con Eloquent. No es el fin de dicho ORM, por lo cual está fuera de su alcance. Si definitivamente quieres trabajarlo a nivel de base de datos, tendrás que pasar la consulta COMPLETA de forma *raw*.

Yo haría la consulta de esta manera, y luego acomodaría la colección según como la necesite (ver documentación):

```
IMSUR\Liquidaciones::with(['liqui_lab','proveedor_p'])
    ->where('cod_proveedor','6869')
    ->select('cod_liquidacion', 'cod_proveedor')
    ->get();
```

El dato que necesitas, sabes que lo encuentras en `liqui_lab->leyes_imsur`, y una vez tengas el resultado de la consulta, puedes crear otra colección a partir de dicho resultado con uno de tantos métodos que existen para el manejo de colecciones, por ejemplo, como punto de partida puedes revisar:

- [map](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-map)
- [flatten](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-flatten)
- [flatMap](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-flatmap)